# Tools for modeling Erlang systems

Tags: erlang

For modeling OO systems a common tool is the class diagram. In Erlang the focus is on processes rather than classes. What tools do you use for modeling Erlang systems and the interactions between processes?

Answer (score 10):

I have been "trying" a bit to sell bigraphs as a model tool. A bigraph is defined to be:

- A hypergraph called the *link* graph. It has a vertices processes and as hyperedges communication between these. In a hypergraph an edge can go between any amount of processes, not only two. In effect the graph maps the communication channels or the communication routes in the program. "Who is talking with whom". Example: [image]
- A tree with the same vertices called the *location* graph. This forms the supervisor-hierarchy which the processes sit in. In other words it maps the responsibility of each process. The further down in the tree it is, the more volatile it is. A process near the root is usually the ones that sit with *state* and have to be protected. Example: [image]

I do hope this will give you a way to visualize and process Erlang programs. If anything is unclear, feel free to prod me.

Comment: How do you distinguish sync vs async communication in the link graph? Are those dashed lines sends or gen_casts and are solid lines gen_calls?

Comment: I guess you could encode that information, but the dashed lines are just communication with the "outside" world, either through sockets or a more high-level HTTP client library. You could make the graph directed, by adding small arrows perhaps - have not given it much time or thought.

Comment: The hypergraph looks like a good fit for describing the overall system. It feels almost as a class diagram but with module names instead of class names.

Comment: It has some similarities to a collaboration diagram - but I hesistated to write that first.

Answer (score 5):

[Sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) can be a good tool for visualising processes and the flow of messages and control between them. I seem to remember that they actually existed before UML.

Comment: Sequence diagrams seems like a good way to visualize a certain use case, but it doesn't provide an overview of the system as a whole. Thanks Robert for your answer and for the excellent course you held last week!

Comment: Oh, and this the best tool I've ever found to write sequence diagrams: http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

Answer (score 3):

- SDL for FSM modeling (OTP) - although the code is also just as easy to read.
- Bi-graph for the supervisor tree
- MSCs for message sequences between processes and/or applications

Answer (score 2):

*Just recently discovered this, even though it was mentioned in 2011 on [Erlang mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-January/055645.html).*

Fundamental Modeling Concepts (FMC):
http://fmc-modeling.org/

It is meant to model software systems, and seems to be at exactly the right level of abstraction. The whole notation is encompassed in just [three different diagram types](http://www.fmc-modeling.org/notation_reference). Look at this beautiful notation (petri-net diagram type):

[image]

They also provide a nice presentation comparing FMC to UML [here](http://www.fmc-modeling.org/fmc-and-uml).